# Algorithmicx multiple statements per line aligned over all lines

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I would like to put  a <- b and e <- f, in parallel on a single line in an algorithmicx environment. I want the same with c <- d and g <- h. Then I want to align both lines. The output shouod look like this.

```
1.    a <- b            e <- f
2.    c <- d            g <- h
```

This is the code I have now:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Test}{}
    \State{$a \gets b$}
    \State{$e \gets f$}
    \State{$c \gets d$}
    \State{$g \gets h$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Could I use the multicolumn environment perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new command `\BiState` which takes two arguments

```
\newcommand{\BiState}[2]{%
  \State{\makebox[2cm]{#1\hfill}#2}%
  }
```

and use it like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\BiState}[2]{%
  \State{\makebox[2cm]{#1\hfill}#2}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Test}{}
    \BiState{$a \gets b$}{$e \gets f$}
    \BiState{$c \gets d$}{$g \gets h$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Adjust `2cm` in its definition to the value that better fits your requirements.

Comment: thanks just what I needed. Your solution works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Test}{}
    \State{$a \gets b \qquad e \gets f$}
    \State{$c \gets d \qquad g \gets h$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, I have many lines in my algorithm. Consequently, this approach will make it very difficult to align all lines.